# swift framework not generating

Tags: ios, swift2

I created framework by using swift on Xcode 8 and got following error. I'm using sqlite3, for that I created `module/module.map` file in project and updated swift compiler search paths.

**Error**

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/xxxxx/Documents/WorkSpace/TestFrame/TestFrame/CatalogDBManager.swift
    cd /Users/xxxxx/Documents/WorkSpace/TestFrame
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
-frontend -c -primary-file /Users/xxxxx/Documents/WorkSpace/TestFrame/TestFrame/CatalogDBManager.swift /Users/xxxxx/Documents/WorkSpace/TestFrame/TestFrame/CatalogDBConfigurations.swift /Users/xxxxx/Documents/WorkSpace/TestFrame/TestFrame/expected.swift
-target x86_64-apple-ios10.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk
-I /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-I /Users/xxxxx/Documents/WorkSpace/TestFrame/TestFrame/module/module.map
-F /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-enable-testing -g -import-underlying-module -module-cache-path /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG
-serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/swift-overrides.hmap
-Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/TestFrame-generated-files.hmap
-Xcc -I/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/TestFrame-own-target-headers.hmap
-Xcc -I/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/TestFrame-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
-Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/all-product-headers.yaml
-Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/TestFrame-project-headers.hmap
-Xcc -I/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
-Xcc -I/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
-Xcc -I/Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/DerivedSources
-Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml
-Xcc -working-directory/Users/xxxxx/Documents/WorkSpace/TestFrame -emit-module-doc-path /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CatalogDBManager~partial.swiftdoc
-Onone -module-name TestFrame -emit-module-path /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CatalogDBManager~partial.swiftmodule
-serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CatalogDBManager.dia
-emit-dependencies-path /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CatalogDBManager.d
-emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CatalogDBManager.swiftdeps
-o /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFrame-gdspwdcbodswscabqloeknuqsacg/Build/Intermediates/TestFrame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestFrame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CatalogDBManager.o

<unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'Swift': Not a directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Xcode 8 not required module.map file, need to copy sqlite3.h file in project directory and make them as public under target membership.And include sqlite3.h file in umbrella header like below

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
```